# Why am I getting the error: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP, when trying to connect to my openSSL based HTTPS server?

Tags: c, ubuntu, server, openssl, backend

I wrote a C backend server that uses OpenSSL version 3.0.2 15 on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

The SSL certificate was issued by Lets Encrypt CA via Certbot(manual DNS CNAME challenge).

When I try to connect to the server using Firefox, some requests end up failing with the following error: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP. The error can be caught in Chrome once in a while although its much more frequent in Firefox.

Here is the full server code:I wrote a C backend server that uses OpenSSL version 3.0.2 15 on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

The SSL certificate was issued by Lets Encrypt CA via Certbot(manual DNS CNAME challenge).

When I try to connect to the server using Firefox, some requests end up failing with the following error: SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP. The error can be caught in Chrome once in a while although its much more frequent in Firefox.

Here is the full server code:

```
//#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/in.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
/* limits.h defines "PATH_MAX". */
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 8192

char HOME[PATH_MAX] = ""; // = "/home/user/backbone/www";
char CERTPATH[PATH_MAX] = ""; // "/etc/letsencrypt/live/opaq.co.il/fullchain.pem";
char  KEYPATH[PATH_MAX] = ""; //"/etc/letsencrypt/live/opaq.co.il/privkey.pem";
//#define LOG_FILE_PATH "/root/log.txt"
char LOG_FILE_PATH[PATH_MAX] = ""; //"/home/user/backbone/log.txt";
//MYSQL *conn;

// FIFO file path
char * myfifo = "/tmp/httpsd";

int getConfig(){
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("/home/itamar/prod/config.txt", "r");
  
    /*File open operation failed.*/
    if (fp == NULL) return -1;

    int indent = 0;
    char arr[4][2][PATH_MAX];
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
      fscanf(fp, "%s", &arr[i][0] [0]);
      fscanf(fp, "%s", &arr[i][1] [0]);
//      printf("%s", arr[i][0]);
      if(strcmp("HOME",arr[i][0]) == 0)
    strcpy(HOME, arr[i][1]);
      if(strcmp("CERTPATH",arr[i][0]) == 0)
        strcpy(CERTPATH, arr[i][1]);
       if(strcmp("KEYPATH",arr[i][0]) == 0)
        strcpy(KEYPATH, arr[i][1]);
      if(strcmp("LOG_FILE_PATH",arr[i][0]) == 0)
        strcpy(LOG_FILE_PATH, arr[i][1]);



      //fscanf(fp, "%s", &arr[i][1] [0]);
      printf("%s: %s\n", arr[i][0], arr[i][1]);
    }
/*
    for (indent = 0; fscanf(fp, "%s\n", buf) == 1; indent++){
        printf("|%s\n",buf);
    strcpy(arr[indent%4][indent%2], buf);
    
    }
    for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++){
    printf("%s %s\n",arr[k][0], arr[k][1]+3);
        if(strcmp(arr[k][0], "HOME")==0){
      strcpy(HOME,arr[k][1]);
    }
    }*/
/*Appending your address into the file...*/
//fprintf(fp, "# %s\n", str);
/*Closing the file...*/
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
//
char mimes[50][2][256] = { {"html","text/html"},
 {"htm","text/html"},
 {"css","text/css"},
 {"js" ,"text/javascript"},
 {"gif" ,"image/gif"},
 {"jpg" ,"image/jpeg"},
 {"jpeg" ,"image/jpeg"},
 {"png" ,"image/png"},
 {"tiff" ,"image/tiff"},
 {"ico" ,"image/x-icon"},
 {"svg" ,"image/svg+xml"},
 {"csv" ,"text/csv"},
 {"txt" ,"text/plain"},
 {"xml" ,"text/xml"},
 {"mpeg" ,"audio/mpeg"},
 {"mp4" ,"video/mp4"},
 {"pdf" ,"application/pdf"},
 };
int telli(char *buf, const char *delim){
  return strcspn(buf, delim);
}

char *tellC(char *buf, const char *delim, int offset, long size){
  char *output = malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(char));
  memset(output, '\0', size);
//  int length = strcspn(buf+offset, delim);
  strncpy(output, buf+offset, strcspn(buf+offset, delim) );
  return output;
}



//--------- SSL FUNCTIONS ---------------------
struct Folder {
  long size;
  char **arr;
  char **type;
};
typedef struct
{
    int sock;
    struct sockaddr address;
    int addr_len;
} connection_t;


SSL_CTX *ctx;
int sock;
struct Folder folder;
//--------LOGGER-----------------------------
int logger(char *str, bool verbose){
 //MYSQL_RES *res;
// MYSQL_ROW row;
/*
  FILE *fp;
 fp = fopen(LOG_FILE_PATH, "a+");
  
  //File open operation failed.
  if (fp == NULL) return -1;
  
  //Appending your address into the file...
  fprintf(fp, "# %s\n", str);
*/  if(verbose)
    printf("| %s\n",str);
  //Closing the file...
  //fclose(fp);*/
  /*char *sql= "INSERT INTO Requests(ip,request) VALUES (\"ip check\",\"";
  char sql2[6] = "\");";
  char *sqlOut = malloc(8500);
  strcpy(sqlOut, sql);
  strcat(sqlOut, str);
  strcat(sqlOut, sql2);
  if (mysql_query(conn, sqlOut)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
    exit(1);
  }
*/
}
//======END OF LOGGER========================

int create_socket(int port)
{
    int s;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(port);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    //inet_addr("82.80.232.19");
    //htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (s < 0) {
        logger("Unable to create socket",true);
        //perror("Unable to create socket");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    int reuse = 1;
    if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, (const char*)&reuse, sizeof(reuse)) < 0)
        logger("INFO: setting sockopt SO_REUSEADR failed", true);
//perror("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");
//    if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &(int){1}, sizeof(int)) < 0)
//        error("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");


    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
        //perror("Unable to bind");
        logger("Unable to bind: will now exit with status EXIT_FAILURE", true);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (listen(s, 1000000) < 0) {
        logger("FATAL: Listen Error. Will now exit",true);
        perror("Unable to listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return s;
}

SSL_CTX *create_context()
{
    const SSL_METHOD *method;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    method = TLS_server_method();
//SSLv23_server_method();
//TLS_server_method();

    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
    if (!ctx) {
        logger("ALERT: Unable to create SSL Context, will now exit with status EXIT_FAILURE", true);
        //perror("Unable to create SSL context");
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version(ctx, TLS1_1_VERSION);
   // SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3);
    //SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "TLSv1.2:TLSv1:SSLv3:!SSLv2:HIGH:!MEDIUM:!LOW");
    return ctx;
}

void configure_context(SSL_CTX *ctx)
{
    /* Set the key and cert */
       if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(ctx, CERTPATH) <= 0 ){ 
//, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
        logger("Cannot set fullchain cert @",true);
        logger(CERTPATH, true);
        logger("Will now exit with status EXIT_FAILURE", true);
   // if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "cert.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, KEYPATH, SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0 ) {
        logger("Cannot set private key @",true);
        logger(KEYPATH,true);
        logger("Will now exit with status EXIT_FAILURE",true);
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
//====== END OF SSL FUNCTIONS================

//-------THREADS-----------------------------

void * process(void * ptr)
{
    //char * buffer;
    int len;
    connection_t * conn;
    //long addr = 0;
printf("test\n");
if (!ptr){
 logger("INFO: Thread did not pass pointer. Exiting Thread. ",true);
 pthread_exit(0);
 return 0;
}
//printf("test1\n");
conn = (connection_t *)ptr;
    //struct sockaddr_in addr;
    //unsigned int length = sizeof(addr);
    SSL *ssl;


    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, conn->sock);
    //do{
    int sslSock = SSL_accept(ssl);
    //===========-----accept--------=================--------
    //do{
     if(sslSock <= 0){
    //if (SSL_accept(ssl) <= 0) {
        //printf("SSL ACCEPT ERROR\n");
        //logger("SSL ACCEPT ERROR",true);
                logger("ALERT: SSL ACCEPT ERROR: Thread will now exit and return 0",true);
//        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    SSL_shutdown(ssl);
    close(conn->sock);
    SSL_free(ssl);
        pthread_exit(0);
        return 0;
    } else {
/*         int error = 0;
    socklen_t len = sizeof (error);
    int retval = getsockopt (conn->sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error, &len);
    if (retval != 0) {
        // there was a problem getting the error code 
        fprintf(stderr, "error getting socket error code: %s\n", strerror(retval));
            return 0;
    }

    if (error != 0) {
            // socket has a non zero error status 
            fprintf(stderr, "socket error: %s\n", strerror(error));
    }*/
    //====================================================================
    //printf("enter accept\n");
    //log(request);

     long addr = (long)((struct sockaddr_in *)&conn->address)->sin_addr.s_addr;
    char address_str[64];
    sprintf(address_str, "%d.%d.%d.%d", 
        (int)((addr      ) & 0xff),
        (int)((addr >>  8) & 0xff),
        (int)((addr >> 16) & 0xff),
        (int)((addr >> 24) & 0xff));
        //char *acceptAddress;
        //acceptAddress = malloc(256);
    //strcpy(acceptAddress, "SSL Accepted Connection: ");
        //strcat(acceptAddress, address_str);
       // logger(acceptAddress,true);
        //printf("SSL Accepted Connection:  ---vvv----");
    //free(acceptAddress);
        //logger(address_str,true);
    //printf("IP: %s\n",address_str);
    
        //FILE* ptr;
/*
        char *line = malloc(8192);
            char *elm = malloc(8192);
            char *request = malloc(8192);
        char *method = malloc(10);

    char *uri = malloc(2048);
    char *home = malloc(2090);
    strcpy(home, HOME);
    char *version = malloc(40);*/
         printf("-----Before SSL_read----\n");
    //char *request = malloc(8192*sizeof char);
    char *request = malloc((BUFFER_SIZE + 1) * sizeof(char));
    memset(request, '\0', BUFFER_SIZE+1);
    int leng = SSL_read(ssl, request, BUFFER_SIZE*sizeof(char) );
    if(leng <= 0){
        SSL_shutdown(ssl);
        close(conn->sock);
        SSL_free(ssl);
        free(conn);
        pthread_exit(0);
        return 0;
    }
    int parsed = 0;
    int offset = 0;
//  printf("Parsing:{\n%s}\n",input);

//  printf("before parse\n");
    //METHOD: GET
    parsed += telli(request+offset," ")+1;
    char *method = tellC(request," ",offset,parsed-offset);
//  printf("%d-%d:[%s]\n",offset,parsed,method);
    offset = parsed;

    //URI: /uri.html
    parsed += telli(request+offset," ")+1;
    char *full_uri = tellC(request," ",offset,parsed-offset);
    int markIndex = strcspn(full_uri,"?");
    char *uri = malloc(PATH_MAX);
    memset(uri, '\0', PATH_MAX);
    if(markIndex < 0){
      strcpy(uri, full_uri);
    }else{
      strncpy(uri, full_uri, markIndex);
    }
    //(full_uri);
//  printf("%d-%d:[%s]\n",offset,parsed,uri);
    offset = parsed;

    //VERSION: HTTP/1.1
    parsed += telli(request+offset,"\r\n")+2;
    char *version = tellC(request,"\r\n",offset,parsed-offset);
//  printf("%d-%d:[%s]\n",offset,parsed,version);
    offset = parsed;
//  printf("after parse\n");
/*
    char *header = tellC(request,"\r\n",offset,parsed-offset);
while(strlen(header) > 0){
        parsed += telli(request+offset,"\r\n")+2;
    //  free(header);
        header = tellC(request,"\r\n",offset,parsed-offset);
//      printf("%d-%d:[%s]\n",offset,parsed,header);
        offset = parsed;
    }
    free(header);*/
    
    char *home = malloc(strlen(HOME)+PATH_MAX+10);
    strcpy(home, HOME);
//  printf("home malloc\n");

    bool isFile = false;
        int j = 0;
        char conType[256]; // = malloc(256);
    
    if(strcmp(uri, "/") == 0){
        isFile = true;
                strcpy(conType, "html");
        strcat(uri, "index.html");
    }else{
        /*
        for(j = 0; j < folder.size; j++){
            //printf("folder.arr[j] %s  uri %s\n", folder.arr[j],uri);
            if(strcmp(folder.arr[j], uri) == 0){
                isFile = true;
                strcpy(conType, folder.type[j]);
                                 //printf("Type---- %s\n",folder.type[j]);
            }
        }*/
            
    }
    isFile = true;
    strcat(home,uri);
//  printf("home: %s\n",home);
    //printf("======== 2 =======\n");
    //=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
/*
int error2 = 0;
socklen_t len2 = sizeof (error2);
int retval2 = getsockopt (conn->sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error2, &len2);
if (retval2 != 0) {
    // there was a problem getting the error code 
    fprintf(stderr, "error getting socket error code: %s\n", strerror(retval2));
    return 0;
}

if (error2 != 0) {
    // socket has a non zero error status 
    fprintf(stderr, "socket error: %s\n", strerror(error2));
}
*/
//----------- end of verify active socket -------
    if(isFile == true){         //inet_ntoa(conn->address.sin_addr)
        //fprintf(stdout, "%s %s %s |%s| 200 OK\n" , version, method, uri);
        /*printf("%d.%d.%d.%d: %s %s |%s| 200 OK\n",
        (int)((addr      ) & 0xff),
            (int)((addr >>  8) & 0xff),
            (int)((addr >> 16) & 0xff),
            (int)((addr >> 24) & 0xff),
            version, method, uri); */
  //              printf("isFile=true\n");
        FILE* file;
        file = fopen(home, "rb");
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END); // seek to end of file
        size_t size = ftell(file); // get current file pointer
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

//      printf("isFile=true after opened file: %s\n",home);
 

//        char* str = malloc(size+100);

        if (NULL == file) {
            logger("ALERT: File cannot be opened: ",true);
            logger(home,true);
        char *response = malloc(8192);
        strcpy(response, "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n");
        SSL_write(ssl, response, strlen(response));
        free(response);
            //printf("file can't be opened \n");
        }else{
      char *response = malloc(8192);
      //strcpy(response, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html;\r\n\r\n");
      strcpy(response, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: ");
      int i = 0;
      char* conT = malloc(2048);
      strcpy(conT,home+strcspn(home,".")+1);
    printf("content Type: %s",conT);
      //printf("Before for\n");
      for(i = 0; mimes[i] != NULL; i++){
      //printf("key: %s \tValue: %s\tType: %s\n",mimes[i][0], mimes[i][1], conType );
        
        if(strcmp(mimes[i][0], conT) == 0){
          strcat(response, mimes[i][1]);
          // printf("----------- %s\n", mimes[i][1]);
          break;
        }
      }
//  printf("After Mimes\n");
      //free(conType);
      //strcat(response, );
      strcat(response, ";\r\n\r\n");
      //logger( response, false);
/*  int error2 = 0;
socklen_t len2 = sizeof (error2);
int retval2 = getsockopt (conn->sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error2, &len2);
if (retval2 != 0) {
    // there was a problem getting the error code 
    fprintf(stderr, "error getting socket error code: %s\n", strerror(retval2));
return 0;
}

if (error2 != 0) {
// socket has a non zero error status 
fprintf(stderr, "socket error: %s\n", strerror(error2));
}
*/

      int write = SSL_write(ssl, response, strlen(response));
     if(write < 20)
        printf("write failed\n"); 
    free(response);

      char *buffer;

//fileptr = fopen("myfile.txt", "rb");  // Open the file in binary mode
//fseek(ptr, 0, SEEK_END);          // Jump to the end of the file
//filelen = ftell(fileptr);             // Get the current byte offset in the file
//rewind(fileptr);                      // Jump back to the beginning of the file

      buffer = (char *)malloc(size * sizeof(char)); // Enough memory for the file
      fread(buffer, size, 1, file); // Read in the entire file
      fclose(file); // Close the file
      /*char* str = malloc(size+100);
      while (fgets(str, size, ptr) != NULL) {
        SSL_write(ssl, str, strlen(str));
      }*/
    
// there was a problem getting the error>

      int out = SSL_write(ssl, buffer, size);
          if( out < size)
        printf("write file out failed\n");
      free(buffer);
    }
    char strOut[PATH_MAX+100];
    snprintf(strOut, PATH_MAX+100,"%d.%d.%d.%d: %s %s |%s| 200 OK", 
            (int)((addr      ) & 0xff),
            (int)((addr >>  8) & 0xff),
            (int)((addr >> 16) & 0xff),
            (int)((addr >> 24) & 0xff),
        version, method, full_uri);
    //snprintf(strOut,256,"%s %s |%s|",version,method,uri);
    logger(strOut, true);
    }else{ //404 not found


        //fprintf(stdout, "Not Found--------404");
        /*printf("%d.%d.%d.%d: %s %s |%s| 404 Not Found\n",
        (int)((addr      ) & 0xff),
            (int)((addr >>  8) & 0xff),
            (int)((addr >> 16) & 0xff),
            (int)((addr >> 24) & 0xff),
            version, method, uri);*/
        char strOut[256];
        snprintf(strOut, 256,"%d.%d.%d.%d: %s %s |%s| 404 Not Found", 
            (int)((addr      ) & 0xff),
            (int)((addr >>  8) & 0xff),
            (int)((addr >> 16) & 0xff),
            (int)((addr >> 24) & 0xff),
        version, method, uri);
        char notfound[] = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>Hi, I'm a 404 Not Found Error!</body></head>";

        SSL_write(ssl, notfound, strlen(notfound));
        logger(strOut, true);
//      free(str);
    }                                                
    //####################################################################
            //SSL_write(ssl, reply, strlen(reply));
    //uri--;
    //}
//  if(str != NULL)
//    free(str);
        //free(ptr);
    free(method);
    free(uri);
    free(version);
    //free(line);
    //free(elm);
        free(request);
         }
/*  SSL_shutdown(ssl);
      close(conn->sock);
        SSL_free(ssl);
*/


    SSL_shutdown(ssl);
    close(conn->sock);
    SSL_free(ssl);
    free(conn);
    //logger("FATAL: Thread will now drop, reason: unkown",true);
    pthread_exit(0);
    return 0;
}
//====== END OF THREADS================

//------ START OF FOLDERS--------------

//1010
static void
list_dir (const char * dir_name, char **buf, long indent, char ** types)
{
    DIR * d;

    /* Open the directory specified by "dir_name". */

    d = opendir (dir_name);

    /* Check it was opened. */
    if (! d) {
        logger("Failed to open directory, will now exit",true);
        fprintf (stderr, "Cannot open directory '%s': %s\n",
                 dir_name, strerror (errno));
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    while (1) {
        struct dirent * entry;
        const char * d_name;

        /* "Readdir" gets subsequent entries from "d". */
        entry = readdir (d);
        if (! entry) {
            /* There are no more entries in this directory, so break
               out of the while loop. */
            break;
        }
        d_name = entry->d_name;
        if(strcmp(d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(d_name, "..") == 0 || (entry->d_type != DT_DIR && entry->d_type != DT_REG))
            continue;
        /* Print the name of the file and directory. */
        if(entry->d_type == DT_REG){
          char *file_uri;
          file_uri = malloc(8192);
          strcpy(file_uri,dir_name+strlen(HOME));
          buf[indent] = malloc(512);
          strcpy(buf[indent], file_uri);
          strcat(buf[indent], "/");
          strcat(buf[indent], d_name);          
          //indent++;
    //type = malloc(1024);
   char typeMe[256];
   strcpy(typeMe, buf[indent]);
   char *token;// = malloc(512);
   //strcpy(token, d_name);
   //printf("token\n");
   // get the first token /
   token = strtok(typeMe, ".");
   //if()
   token = strtok(NULL, ".");
//1020
   types[indent] = malloc(512);
   //printf("malloc types indent (%s)\n",token);
   strcpy(types[indent], token);

   // walk through other tokens /
   //printf("after copy: %s\n",types[indent]);
   while( token != NULL ) {
      //printf( " %s\n", token );
    
      token = strtok(NULL, ".");
   }
   //free(token);
  //       printf("after while\n");
          char *logREG;
          logREG = malloc(18300);
          strcpy(logREG, "Loaded: ");
          strcat(logREG,buf[indent]);
          strcat(logREG, " type: ");
          //printf("before REG Load: %s\n", buf[indent]);
          strcat(logREG, types[indent]);
          logger(logREG ,true);
          free(logREG);
     //     while( token != NULL) token = strtok(NULL, ".");
       //   free(token);
          free(file_uri);
          indent++;
        }
#if 0
        /* If you don't want to print the directories, use the
           following line: */

        if ( (entry->d_type == DT_REG)) {
//          printf ("%s/%s\n", dir_name, d_name);
        }

#endif /* 0 */


        if (entry->d_type & DT_DIR) {

            /* Check that the directory is not "d" or d's parent. */
            
            if (strcmp (d_name, "..") != 0 &&
                strcmp (d_name, ".") != 0) {
                int path_length;
                char path[PATH_MAX];
 
                path_length = snprintf (path, PATH_MAX,
                                        "%s/%s", dir_name, d_name);
                
//                printf ("%s\n", path);
                if (path_length >= PATH_MAX) {
                    fprintf (stderr, "Path length has got too long.\n");
                    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
                /* Recursively call "list_dir" with the new path. */
//              indent++;
                list_dir (path, buf, indent, types);
                indent++;
            }
        }
    }
    /* After going through all the entries, close the directory. */
    if (closedir (d)) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Could not close '%s': %s\n",
                 dir_name, strerror (errno));
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
//======== END OF FOLDERS===============
void * interpreter(){
  while(1){
    char str1[80];
    memset(str1, '\0', 80);
    int fd1 = open(myfifo,O_RDONLY);
    read(fd1, str1, 80);

    // Print the read string and close
    int index = strcspn(str1,"\n");
    char message[80];
    memset(message, '\0', 80);
    strncpy(message,str1,index);
    printf("CLI: |%s|\n", message);
    close(fd1);
    if(strcmp(message,"exit") == 0){
           logger("Will now exit due to user command.\n", true);
       exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  
  }//while(1);
  pthread_exit(0);
  return 0;
}

//========== MAIN ==============
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

    int cnf = getConfig();
    //MYSQL *conn;
    //MYSQL_RES *res;
    //MYSQL_ROW row;

    char *server = "localhost";
    char *user = "webvm";
    char *password = "Aa123456"; /* set me first */
    char *database = "web";

    //conn = mysql_init(NULL);
    /* Connect to database  
    if (!mysql_real_connect(conn, server, user, password,database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", mysql_error(conn));
        exit(1);
    }*/
    //printf("num %d\n",PATH_MAX);
//int fd1;

// FIFO file path
//char * myfifo = "/tmp/httpsd";

// Creating the named file(FIFO)
// mkfifo(<pathname>,<permission>)
mkfifo(myfifo, 0666);

//char str1[80];
//char str2[80]= ">";

    logger("_____Server Start_____", true); 
    folder.arr = malloc(65536*1999);
    folder.type = malloc(65536);
    list_dir (HOME, folder.arr, 0, folder.type);
//    printf("Loaded: %ld\n", indent);//folder.arr[0]);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; folder.arr[i] != NULL; i++){
      //printf("Loaded: %s\n", folder.arr[i]);//folder.arr[0]);
    }
    folder.size = i;
    char *printFileSize;
    printFileSize = malloc(256);
    snprintf(printFileSize, 256,"Folder tree size: %ld",folder.size);
    //printf("Ammount of Files: %ld\n", folder.size);
    logger(printFileSize, true);
     printf("Server up\n");
    
    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
//  connection_t * connection;
//  pthread_t thread;
    //---------------------------
     
/*
    ctx = create_context();

    configure_context(ctx);
*/
    //sock = create_socket(8080);
    sock = create_socket(443);
//    sock = create_socket(80);

    /* Handle connections */

    pthread_t thread_input;
    pthread_create(&thread_input, 0, interpreter, NULL);
   // pthread_detach(thread_input);
   
   //pthread_t thread_keepAlive;
    //pthread_create(&thread_keepAlive, 0, (void *)keepalive, &sock);
    
   
    do
    {
        ctx = create_context();
        configure_context(ctx);
//          printf("waiting to accept...\n");
        connection_t * connection;
        pthread_t thread;
        connection = (connection_t *)malloc(sizeof(connection_t));
        connection->sock = accept(sock, &connection->address, &connection->addr_len);
//      printf("Accept\n");
        if (connection->sock <= 0)
        {
            free(connection);
        }
        else
        {
    pthread_create(&thread, 0, process, (void *)connection);
    pthread_detach(thread);
        }
    }while(1);

    /*
    while(1) {
        struct sockaddr_in addr;
        unsigned int len = sizeof(addr);
        SSL *ssl;
//        const char reply[] = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n<html><body><style>p{background: red}</style><p>Nothing is true, everything is permitted</p><p>hello friends</p><p> sup my homie?</p><p>veredN1</p><p>Between and Under the words</p><p>BETWEEN</p><p>we are born in one day,</p><p>EVERYTHING can happen in 1 day</p></body></html>";

        int client = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, &len);
        if (client < 0) {
            perror("Unable to accept");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
        SSL_set_fd(ssl, client);
    //===========-----accept--------=================--------
        if (SSL_accept(ssl) <= 0) {
            ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        } else {
            //====================================================================

            FILE* ptr;
            char *line = malloc(8192);
            char *elm = malloc(8192);
            char *request = malloc(8192);

//-----------------------------------------------
            SSL_read(ssl, request, 8192);
//------------------------------------------------
            char *method = malloc(10);
            char *uri = malloc(2048);
            char *home = malloc(2090);
            strcpy(home, HOME);
            char *version = malloc(40);

            line = strtok(request, "\r\n");
            elm = strtok(line, " ");

            strcpy(method, elm);
            elm = strtok(NULL, " ");
            strcpy(uri, elm);
            elm = strtok(NULL, " ");
            strcpy(version, elm);

            while(  line!= NULL ) {
                line = strtok(NULL, "\r\n");
            }
            while(  elm!= NULL ) {
                elm = strtok(NULL, " ");
            }
//========= STRING MANIPULATION SECTION =======

        bool isFile = false;
        //switch(uri){
        if(strcmp(uri, "/") == 0){
            isFile = true;
            strcat(uri, "index.html");
        }else{
            for(int j = 0; j < folder.size; j++){
                if(strcmp(folder.arr[j], uri) == 0){
                    isFile = true;
                }
            }
            
        }
        strcat(home,uri);
                                    
    if(isFile == true){         
        fprintf(stdout, "%s %s %s |%s| 200 OK\n", inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), version, method, uri);

        ptr = fopen(home, "r");
        fseek(ptr, 0, SEEK_END); // seek to end of file
        size_t size = ftell(ptr); // get current file pointer
        fseek(ptr, 0, SEEK_SET);
        char* str = malloc(size+100);

        if (NULL == ptr) {
            printf("file can't be opened \n");
        }else{
            while (fgets(str, size, ptr) != NULL) {
                SSL_write(ssl, str, strlen(str));
            }
        }     

    }else{ //404 not found
        //fprintf(stdout, "Not Found--------404");
        fprintf(stdout, "%s %s %s |%s| 404 Not Found\n", inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr), version, method, uri);
        char notfound[] = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\n\r\n<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>Hi, I'm a 404 Not Found Error!</body></head>";
        SSL_write(ssl, notfound, strlen(notfound));
    }                                                

    free(method);
    free(uri);
    free(version);
    free(line);
    free(elm);

    }

    SSL_shutdown(ssl);
        SSL_free(ssl);
        close(client);
    }*/
    //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    /*
    //--------------- START OF ORIGINAL THREADING------------------------------
    int sock = -1;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int port = 80;
    connection_t * connection;
    pthread_t thread;

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(port);
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: error: cannot bind socket to port %d\n", argv[0], port);
        return -4;
    }

    if (listen(sock, 500) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: error: cannot listen on port\n", port);
        return -5;
    }

    printf("%d: ready and listening\n", port);
    
    while (1)
    {
        connection = (connection_t *)malloc(sizeof(connection_t));
        connection->sock = accept(sock, &connection->address, &connection->addr_len);
        if (connection->sock <= 0)
        {
            free(connection);
        }
        else
        {
            pthread_create(&thread, 0, process, (void *)connection);
            pthread_detach(thread);
        }
    }
    //============== END OF ORIGINAL THREADING ===================== */
//  mysql_free_result(res);
    //mysql_close(conn);
    close(sock);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
    return 0;
}
```

I used the following to compile the code:

```
gcc -o server server.c -lssl -lcrypto -pthread
```

I tried verfying that the issue didn't stem from OpenSSL's version.
Set the setting to a minimum required TLS version as 1.3 to force the usage of TLS1.3 cipher suites using the command SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version(ctx, TLS1_3_VERSION);

Used both options to create an SSL Method:

```
TLS_server_method();
SSLv23_server_method();
```

Comment: One common reason for this is that your server doesn't have or can't find its certifcate and/or private key.

Comment: The thing is only some of the connections fail due to that error and some pass fine which means the server was able to use the certificates and therefore it must have found it